# Default audio device selection not working

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, 16.10

I set a device to be the default:

[image: default selected output 2]

But when I open a new audio application, it ignores my selection:

[image: selects output 1 instead]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I went to **Audio and Video** (Phonon Audio and Video) and had to change the order of the Devices listed under **Audio hardware setup**
This fixed the issue for me running Kubuntu 16:10 with KDE Plasma.